# How to handle (avoid): "Fail to create runspace because you have exceeded your budget to create runspace."

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, httprequest, exchange-server, runspace

I have HTTP triggered Azure Function App on PowerShell Core stack. Script is parsing the body of the request, assuming that everything is ok, it connects to Exchange Online and then executes 2 cmdlets to create *MailContact* type of contact. At the end it disconnects from Exchange Online. I have console app that is executing POST requests passing JSON data for one contact in the body. Requests are executed in a for-each loop and after 5th successful requests I get runspace exceeded budget error.

some code snippets from the script

...

```
    try {

     Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbprint $thumb -AppId $appId -Organization $org -Showbanner:$false -CommandName Get-Contact,Get-MailContact,New-MailContact,Set-Contact,Set-MailContact,Remove-MailContact

     New-MailContact -ErrorAction stop @p | Out-Null

     Set-Contact -ErrorAction stop @parameters | Out-Null

    } 
    catch {
      ...
    } 
    finally {
  
         Disconnect-ExchangeOnline -Confirm:$false -InformationAction Ignore -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    
         Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession    
    }
```

What I tried (without success):

- relaxation for Exchange Online throttling policy (https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/3205/self-service-powershell-throttling-policy-relaxation-for-exchange-online)
- setting different environmental variables (like PSWorkerInProcConcurrencyUpperBound and FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT)

What worked: having additional Function App and then cycle every 5 requests between the two.

Additional information that might help:

- PSWorkerInProcConcurrencyUpperBound  = 1000
- FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT = 10
- Function runtime version = ~4
- PowerShell Core Version = 7
- Platform = 64Bit
- Plan type = Consumption (Serverless)

On addition, it takes around 7-8 sec from sending request till I get the response back. Connecting to Exchange Online takes a lot of time.

Any help or hint how to solve the runspace budget error ?

Comment: to me, the wording of that msg indicates that you have a budget problem. take a look at what your limits are on how much _money_ you are spending.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I would say that "Budget" in this context has a different meaning. Plan type is "Consumption" - cost depends on the usage.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

Comment: ok ... then i have no more ideas. [*sigh ...*] i will go back to lurking ... and i wish you the best of good luck! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

a dirty workaround would be this:

```
try {
    Connect-ExchangeOnline @ConnectExchange
} catch {
    Write-Verbose -Verbose ($_.Exception.Message)
    $Wait = ($_.Exception.Message) | Select-String ('(?<=for )(.*)(?= seconds)') -AllMatches
    $Count = ([int]$Wait.Matches.Value)
    Start-Sleep -seconds $Count
    
    Connect-ExchangeOnline @ConnectExchange
}
```